# Replacing \r\n with <br />

Tags: php, html, forms

Basically i'm trying to set something where a user enters some text into a textarea (and they press their enter key to add new lines) and then it takes the value from that text area and mails it out in the message of a new email to a specified contact.

All the mailing functionality works, but I need to be able to automatically add a new line when the user presses enter in the textarea.

Using this to get the info from the previous page/form and replace the \r\n:

```
$BREAKINGNEWS=$_POST['BREAKINGNEWS'];
$NEWS = str_replace("\r\n","<br />",$BREAKINGNEWS);
```

Then just adding $NEWS into the code to mail it out.

Doesn't seem to work though, just puts it on 1 line and doesn't replace the \r\n!

Any help is most appreciated :)

Comment: use nl2br() function. It will not replace the new line to br but it will append br with new line character. This will also resolves your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) built in

Comment: @Noah, then you probably don't actually have `\n` in there.

Comment: There's no reason it shouldn't. The problem most likely lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

[nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) really works.

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/0e270

Answer (score 1):

There's the [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function built-in to PHP which does exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use nl2br. It will respect all different formats like \n, \r or \r\n (http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)